# Qvector code changing to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, vector

I have a question about OpenCV in xcode.
I was following the tutorial from:
http://thisoldhack.blogspot.com/2010/11/opencv-surf-and-qt.html

And i need to insert some code in xcode:

// Find matching keypoints in both images

```
QVector<QVector<CvPoint2D32f> > keyPointMatches;
keyPointMatches.append(QVector<CvPoint2D32f>());
keyPointMatches.append(QVector<CvPoint2D32f>());
```

But this does not work for xcode becouse i dont have include Qvector4D in my code.
Does someone know how i can change this code so it works with my xcode program?

greetings, Dennis